# Bounded Input Bounded State stability

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes

For a state space system $$\dot{\vec{x}} = A \vec{x} + B \vec{u}$$ I understand that if the real components of all eigenvalues of the matrix A are $< 0$, then the system is bounded input bounded state stable. I also understand that if the system does have a real component $\geqslant 0$, it doesn't necessarily mean that the system is unstable. My question is, can you conclude that an unstable system always has at least one real component $\geqslant 0$?

Comment: No. Consider the eigenalues of $A=\left(\begin{array} {rr}-1&-2\\-2&-1\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Can you please elaborate? You're answer doesn't really seem to answer the question. The eigenvalues of that matrix are 1 and -3, but that doesn't show that a system which is not bounded input bounded state stable always has at least one real component of an eigenvalue ⩾ 0.

Comment: If you mean the  real component *of an eigenvalue*, then the answer is yes. If an unstable system does not have eigenvalues with nonegative real parts, it has only eigenvalues with negative real parts, hence, it must be stable.  It is a contradiction.